# Constant Class for API Method Names

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am looking at a project that makes calls to an API (within C# code so this is taking place server-side). There are dozens of methods and so you might see something like 
    `/API/GetValue1` , `/API/Search/` , `/API/AnotherThing`,  or   `/API/Something/DoSomethingElse/1234411(some ID)`

For all of this right now it's hard-coded into each of the calls, and likely won't change, but you never know.

Can all of this be moved into a constants class and so I could replace the occurence of `/API/GetValue1`  with something like `MyConstantClass.Value1` and it would automatically put that as the URL path for the endpoint?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean. It's in the client side, in the server side? Also, if it's in the client side, how are you doing your calls?

Comment: Server side. I'm making these calls using http client in .net code

Comment: If you are using web api, you just need to give a routeTemplate when you configure your route, the Something/DoSomethingElse will came out from controller's name and id... take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624180/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-Web-API

Comment: Without code we have no idea what you're talking about. If you add code it might be better suited for codereview.se

Comment: I know that magic strings are a bit of a code smell, but... it seems like a redundant layer of abstraction. Yes it may help of you change the method names. But if you have a substantial change, you're going to have a bunch of constant identifiers in your code that don't resemble the method. Also what happens if a method is removed or split into two?

Answer (score 1):

That's what you should do. Create a static class to contain all of your API endpoints. Never use magic strings directly in code, because they are error-prone.